# When to use Dynamic Test in Junit 5

Tags: java, junit

Have been reading docs for Junit 5.0.
Have noticed a new method has been introduced `@TestFactory`. What would be good example of the `@TestFactory` usage, when you would actually create one of those?

Peter

Comment: seems an equivalent of testng `@Factory` - here http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic tests generation is useful when you need to run the same set of tests on many different input values or configurations.

```
@TestFactory
Stream<DynamicTest> dynamicTestsFromIntStream() {
    // Generates tests for the first 10 even integers.
    return IntStream.iterate(0, n -> n + 2).limit(10).mapToObj(
            n -> dynamicTest("test" + n, () -> assertTrue(n % 2 == 0)));
}
```

Or one more complex example. You can define your own DSL to describe test suites and store them in the non-source files. Then you can read and process these files accordingly and generate dynamic test based on the input.

Comment: Why is it better than just using parameterized test? or just creating those numbers and asserting them in a basic loop?